Next JS Links sending users to wrong page on Firebase Hosting
Background: I am using NextJS hosted on Firebase hosting. My pages all have a Navbar component with an "Account" button. The button is a NextJS Link with href="/account".
When testing locally, it works fine (sends the user to "/account"). When testing on my Firebase-hosted site, clicking the link sends me to "/acc" instead of "/account". The bizarre thing is, hovering over the Account button on Chrome, you can see the redirect URL on the bottom left of the page, and if you right-click the account button and copy link address, they both show the link /account.
I'm trying to figure this out, so please help me!
Navbar component:
export default function Navbar({
  currentUser,
  handleSignOut,
  handleSignIn,
}: NavbarProps) {
  return (
    <div className="w-full h-20 flex justify-between items-center px-5 fixed top-0">
      <div className="flex-shrink-0 h-full">
        <Link href="/">
          <div className="h-full w-48 relative">
            <Image
              src="/white.png"
              alt="Logo"
              layout="fill"
              style={{ objectFit: "contain", objectPosition: "left" }}
            />
          </div>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <div className="flex gap-4">
        {currentUser ? (
          <>
            <Link
              href="/account"
              as={"/account"}
              className="bg-white text-black py-2 px-5 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-200 font-bold font-roboto-flex-bold"
              onClick={(e) => {
                console.log(
                  "Account link clicked, href:",
                  e.currentTarget.href
                );
              }}
            >
              Account
            </Link>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                handleSignOut();
              }}
              className="bg-none text-white py-2 px-5 rounded-lg font-bold font-roboto-flex-bold"
            >
              Sign Out
            </button>
          </>
        ) : (
          <>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                handleSignIn();
              }}
              className="bg-white text-black py-2 px-5 rounded-lg hover:bg-gray-200 font-bold font-roboto-flex-bold"
            >
              Sign Up
            </button>
            <button
              onClick={() => {
                handleSignIn();
              }}
              className="bg-none text-white py-2 px-5 rounded-lg font-bold font-roboto-flex-bold"
            >
              Login
            </button>
          </>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

My next config file:
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  output: "export",
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
  trailingSlash: true,
};

module.exports = nextConfig;

My firebase.json file:
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log",
        "*.local"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "hosting": {
    "source": "frontend",
    "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1"
    }
  }
}

What am I doing wrong?

I suggest creating a brand new project with just enough code that causes the problem, then share all of that code here (a complete minimal reproducible example).  We need to be sure that there is nothing else in your project that might be causing the problem that we can't see here.

Definitely considering that. Part of the project was imported from elsewhere but I was hoping somebody had seen this before. Even Perplexity AI couldn't figure this one out

It's worth more than a consideration - an MCVE is essentially a requirement for posting good questions on Stack Overflow. Without seeing all the moving parts, all we can do is guess what might be wrong.

Hey Doug - I recreated the project and the issue stopped.

I took @Doug Stevenson (in the comments) suggestion to create a brand new project, pasted my existing code in, and it works fine.
For future reference, if anyone runs into this, just recreate your project. Took < 5 min to copy everything over

It would be helpful to know what the root cause was so that someone with a much larger project will not have to deal with copying everything over
